# Width of Canvas Square not being Constant

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So this is my first time using the canvas in js, and I am trying to move the square, when it does move, the left side of the square just stays the same and it just gets wider. For example, if I press the 'd' key, the right side of the square keeps expanding and the left side does not move. Thanks!

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let px = 0;
let directx = {"right": false, "left": false};
let speed = 6;

canvas.style.backgroundColor = "red";
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

document.addEventListener("keydown", startmove);

function startmove(event){
    if(event.key == "d"){
        directx.right = true;
        directx.left = false;
    }
    else if(event.key == "a"){
        directx.right = false;
        directx.left = true;
    }
}
function move(){
    context.fillRect(px, 0, 100, 100);
    if(directx.right == true){
        px = px + speed;
    }
    else if(directx.left == true){
        px = px - speed;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
move();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I tried finding a way to constantly set the width of the square, but that didnt work :(

Answer (score 2):

Your square is moving but you're not clearing the previous frame hence it looks like it is expanding. You can use [clearRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect) to clear the canvas.

```js
let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
let width = window.innerWidth;
let height = window.innerHeight;
let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
let px = 0;
let directx = {"right": false, "left": false};
let speed = 6;

canvas.style.backgroundColor = "red";
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

document.addEventListener("keydown", startmove);

function startmove(event){
    if(event.key == "d"){
        directx.right = true;
        directx.left = false;
    }
    else if(event.key == "a"){
        directx.right = false;
        directx.left = true;
    }
}
function move(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    context.fillRect(px, 0, 100, 100);
    if(directx.right == true){
        px = px + speed;
    }
    else if(directx.left == true){
        px = px - speed;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
move();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```